# What is RAW_REQUESTS in Binance API rate limit

Tags: binance, binance-api-client

The `/api/v3/exchangeInfo` returns the following rate limits

[image]

Binance documentation says:

> Endpoints related to /api/*:
>
> - According to the two modes of IP and UID (account) limit, each are independent.
> - Endpoints share the 1200 per minute limit based on IP, excluding the new order endpoint POST /api/v3/order which has specific limits of 50
>   per 10 seconds and 160000 per day based on UID.
> - Responses contain the header X-MBX-USED-WEIGHT-(intervalNum)(intervalLetter), defining the weight
>   used by the current IP.
> - Successful order responses contain the header X-MBX-ORDER-COUNT-(intervalNum)(intervalLetter), defining the order
>   limit used by the UID.

So headers start with `X-MBX-USED-WEIGHT-` are related to `rateLimits[0]`, headers start with `X-MBX-ORDER-COUNT-` are related to `rateLimits[1]` and `rateLimits[2]`.

What about `rateLimits[3]`? How do I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

`rateLimits[0]` guaranteed there will not be more than 6000 requests in 5 minutes, so `rateLimits[3]` is actually a redundant.

I guess it's an old version of rate limits they forget to remove, that's why documents didn't mention it.

Comment: rateLimits[3] might be simply stating that there can be no more than 6000 request to the API no matter the weight.

Comment: @mcv_dev Then we have to count this in client side, because the Binance header doesn't return it. There will be ping and other problems that make this count different from the Binance server side, so I doubt that's it.

Comment: The doc lacks of information on this point. I have the same question because, on the /sapi end points, the doc states that there is an IP limit of 12000 (12k). And that is not given by api/v3/exhangeInfo.